# JS Drive API: Files.List Returning 500 Internal Server Errors

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-client

**Update**

I took the working request (copied to cURL) from the API explorer (with the 'id' field defined) and replaced the API Key in the URL and Authorization header with the ones from the successful request (without the 'id' field defined). Running this request then failed. So the exact same headers (apart from Authorization) and the exact same request (except key) are failing when using my own credentials with a 500 error. Additionally these same credentials are able to make other requests to the Drive API so they are actually valid.

**Update 2**

Here is the cURL request taken from the API Explorer with  and  removed. When these are replaced with my own key/token the request returns a 500 error. The exact same request with "(id)" removed from it however DOES work with my own key/token.

`curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=trashed%3Dfalse+and+%27root%27+in+parents&fields=items(id)%2CnextPageToken&key=<KEY>' -H 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' -H 'X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable: base64' -H 'X-Origin: https://developers.google.com' -H 'X-ClientDetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Macintosh%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010_10_1)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F40.0.2214.115%20Safari%2F537.36&platform=MacIntel&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Macintosh%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010_10_1)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F40.0.2214.115%20Safari%2F537.36' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36' -H 'Referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.9OJnLZReRBQ.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Ft%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOvQmx_voM6JiXRxPIdYyD-EV0zsQ' -H 'X-JavaScript-User-Agent: google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0-beta' -H 'X-Referer: https://developers.google.com' --compressed`

My token is authorized with the following scopes:
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"

**Original Post**

A couple days ago a files.list query that was being run every page load started always returning 500 (Internal Server Error) responses. I am using the JS google client lib to run the files.list request. The same request run through the APIs explorer is working.

I can make the files.list request succeed by either removing the 'fields' param or by simplifying the 'fields' param to just be 'items,nextPageToken' rather than 'items(id),nextPageToken'.

The code running the request simplified below:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list(
{
    fields: 'items(id),nextPageToken',
    maxResults: 50,
    q: "trashed=false and 'root' in parents",
    pageToken: undefined
});

...

// Async
request.execute();
```

Here are the requests sent from the API explorer and the page (broken and working version). I'm not seeing any diffs between them apart from different encoding of the 'q' param from the API explorer (and some headers...). Given that the different encoding does work without the 'id' field specified and replacing the 'q' param in the request with the API explorer encoded version does not fix the problem.

**Request Sent From API Explorer - Works**

`https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=50&q=trashed%3Dfalse+and+%27root%27+in+parents&fields=items(id)%2CnextPageToken&key=<API KEY>`

**Request Sent From Page (with fields) - Broken**

`https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=50&q=trashed%3Dfalse%20and%20%27root%27%20in%20parents&fields=items(id)%2CnextPageToken&key=<API KEY>`

**Request Sent From Page (without fields) - Works**

`https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=50&q=trashed%3Dfalse%20and%20%27root%27%20in%20parents&fields=items%2CnextPageToken&key=<API_KEY>`

Am I missing something obvious here? Am I failing to properly encode the fields parameter somehow (encodeURIComponent causes 'Invalid Request' errors)? Can someone else reproduce the same issue, or they are already seeing it?

Thanks!

Comment: look at the http traffic in chrome dev console and compare it with the traffic sent using https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it

Comment: Updated post with the requests, should have posted that before. The only difference between the working and non-working requests from the page is the (id) field which is encoded the same way in the working request from the API explorer.

Comment: And after a little bit more exploration - taking the exact working query from the API explorer and replacing with my own credentials then gets a 500 error from the server. Those same credentials are able to make other file.list requests so they are definitely valid.

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it, the encoding of item sub-fields is 
?fields=items%2Fid%2CnextPageToken

Comment: Thanks for the response! According to https://developers.google.com/drive/web/performance#partial-response I should be able to use either items/id or items(id) [I also tried switching to using items/id and I still receive a 500 error - and verified the encoding was correct]. The exact query was working a few days ago so this is a recent change.

Comment: You are saying that you have a successful request via API explorer, but when you switch to your credentials it fails?  What scopes are you including?  You are sure that you are authed on the user's drive?

Comment: Hi Cheryl - Yes that is what I am seeing. Additionally, the same request with the same credentials with a change to the 'fields' param allows the request to return correctly. Only when I am requesting a partial 'items' response is there an issue. I added the authorized scopes to the post above, and I am quite sure that the credentials I am using are authorized to access my drive. This same query has been working for months but I noticed it stopped a few days ago (unsure of exact timeframe unfortunately).

Comment: Fyi, we are looking into it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Poking around with credentials a bit more I can actually get the API Explorer to fail with a 500 error if I authenticate with BOTH "drive.file" and "drive.metadata.readonly". If I authenticate with ONLY "drive.metadata.readonly" the same request is successful.

Comment: Oh, interesting... Would you mind sharing your app id and account you've made requests too?

Comment: Sure. Trying the same requests on other accounts does appear to work as well when they have the same auth scopes.
AppID: 597847337936
Account: grant.watters@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks.. They were able to repro the issue now with the multiple scopes.  Sorry for the regression.  Hopefully they will have a fix out soon.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue as well, using drive.file and drive.metadata.readonly. Luckily I'm developing my app so for now i use the full drive scope druring testing. Hope this is fixed soon. Using fields makes the requests go much faster.

Comment: We are unfortunately still seeing this issue - is there any update on a possible ETA?